# Using Karma in Angular4-cli project after ng eject

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, angular-cli

After using the `ng eject` command for using webpack and his config file, all the test enviroment stopped working.

Using `npm test` deploys a karma instance but no test are executed, this is the output:

```
26 05 2017 09:20:47.957:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
26 05 2017 09:20:47.969:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.4.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
26 05 2017 09:20:47.970:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
26 05 2017 09:20:47.977:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
26 05 2017 09:20:49.389:INFO [Chrome 58.0.3029 (Windows 10 0.0.0)]:
```

I've tried adding into my `karma.conf.js`the following configuration as suggested by [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5553) open issue but this isn't working.

My reportes configured in the project are:

```
reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
      ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul']
      : ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
```